# Does iOS Playgrounds supports UIView animations?

Tags: ios, uikit, swift-playground

Is it possible to preview animation done for UIView with animateWithDuration in Playground? I am adding XCPShowView right after initialization of UIView and its shows everything it in a final state no matter what position on a timeline I will choose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 7 update : `XCPShowView` is deprecated but you can see the animation in the playground liveView. And there is more coming soon: [Interactive Playgrounds](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=35)

Here is an update to Joseph Chen sample code. I also changed the color to green as the container default background is black :

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
// XCPShowView("container", view: container)  // -> deprecated

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
container.addSubview(view)

UIView.animateWithDuration(5) {
    view.center = CGPoint(x: 75.0, y: 75.0)
}

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView=container
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is (checked on Xcode 6.1.1, but may apply to earlier versions).

You should:

1. Select the "Run in Full Simulator" option (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26806215/2880276) for a step-by-step).
2. Add the view you wish to animate within a container view.

For example, this shows a black square moving in a down-left motion:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
XCPShowView("container", container)

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
container.addSubview(view)

UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, animations: { () -> Void in
    view.center = CGPoint(x: 75.0, y: 75.0)
})
```