# UIView Animation without "Run in Full Simulator" in Xcode 7.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to do a simple flip animation between two views in a Playground using UIView.transitionFromView. As described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192741/does-ios-playgrounds-supports-uiview-animations), older versions of Xcode simply required the option "Run in Full Simulator" to be selected, but that is no longer available in **Playground Settings** under **Platform** for Xcode 7.1.

In my working example, the bottom view is always immediately shown.  The transition is performed, but with any animation:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func flipFrontToBack(frontView: UIView, backView: UIView) {

   let transitionOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft

   var views : (frontView: UIView, backView: UIView)

   views = (frontView: frontView, backView: backView)

   UIView.transitionFromView(views.frontView,
      toView: views.backView,
      duration: 2.0,
      options: transitionOptions,
      completion: { _ in
   })
}

func smallSquare(backgroundColor: UIColor, borderColor: UIColor) ->     UIView {
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
    let view = UIView(frame: bounds)
    view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    view.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 5
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    return view
}

func makeView() -> UIView {
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200)
    let view = UIView(frame: bounds)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 5
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    return view
}

let view = makeView()

var frontCard = smallSquare(UIColor.blackColor(), borderColor: UIColor.whiteColor())
var backCard = smallSquare(UIColor.whiteColor(), borderColor: UIColor.redColor())

view.addSubview(backCard)
view.addSubview(frontCard)
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view

flipFrontToBack(frontCard, backView: backCard)
```

My code works in my project in Xcode.  I'm simply trying to migrate it to a Playground so I can prototype some additional changes.  By commenting out the ** flipFrontToBack()** method, you can see the unflipped and "flipped" image.  So, I get the flip, but no animation.

[image: Unflipped]

[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What was it that you expected Run In Full Simulator to do for you?

Comment: I'm trying to do UIView animations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192741/does-ios-playgrounds-supports-uiview-animations

Comment: Did you read the docs? This has all changed in 7.1: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/XCPlaygroundModuleRef/XCPlayground.html

Comment: Why yes I did.  This line should have indicated that I read it: XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view  ... I didn't include needsIndefiniteExecution = true in my example but I did set it in my playground

Comment: Well, as you probably know, I think playgrounds are the work of the devil, so it's not something I'm going to get my knickers in a twist about. I stick with actual apps, and I don't quite see why you'd want this to work in a playground, esp. since you have it working in real life already. :)

Comment: You're doing that thing where you're telling me that I shouldn't want to do what I want to do.  I agree Playgrounds are a little limited but they are still kind of cool. I'm building out my own little Swift Cookbook and I'd like to do an iOS one too: http://www.h4labs.com/dev/ios/swift_cookbook.html

Comment: Not at all. I'm doing that thing where I couldn't figure it out and I had no expectation or desire that it would work in the first place so I stopped caring and walked away.

Comment: It has been figured out. I'll blog a better answer at some point.

Answer (score 2):

I made a little progress.  I had to use an NSTimer to schedule the flip for at least 0.1 seconds.  The container flips, and not the two cards, but that's another issue.  I also refactored into a class because they seem to be easier to work with once you get beyond a few lines.  Anyway, some "working" code:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class MyView: UIView {

    var frontCard:UIView!
    var backCard:UIView!

    func makeView() {

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 5
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    }


    func flipFrontToBack(frontView: UIView, backView: UIView) {

        let transitionOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.    TransitionFlipFromLeft

        var views : (frontView: UIView, backView: UIView)

        views = (frontView: frontView, backView: backView)
        /*
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413539/uiview-    transitionwithview-swift-syntax
        */

        UIView.transitionFromView(views.frontView,
            toView: views.backView,
            duration: 2.0,
            options: transitionOptions,
            completion: { _ in
        })
    }

    func smallSquare(backgroundColor: UIColor, borderColor:     UIColor) -> UIView {
        let bounds = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
        let view = UIView(frame: bounds)
        view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        view.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 5
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        return view
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        frontCard = smallSquare(UIColor.blackColor(), borderColor:     UIColor.whiteColor())
        backCard = smallSquare(UIColor.whiteColor(), borderColor:     UIColor.redColor())

        makeView()

        self.addSubview(backCard)
        self.addSubview(frontCard)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func update() {
        flipFrontToBack(frontCard, backView: backCard)
    }

    func flipIt() {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self,     selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }
}

let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200)
let view = MyView(frame: bounds)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
view.flipIt() // Works if NSTimer > 0
//view.update() // Doesn't work.  Flips immediately
```